# When or why would we want to use one of the smooth approximation functions for the ReLU?

Tags: machine-learning, relu

Learning about the ReLU, I keep finding variants or approximations that attempt to smooth out the function (eg. squarreplus).

Why (and when) is smoothing desirable?

Comment: The abstract to the Squareplus paper answers this question directly: "We present squareplus, an activation function that resembles softplus, but which can be computed using only algebraic operations: addition, multiplication, and square-root. Because squareplus is ~6x faster to evaluate than softplus on a CPU and does not require access to transcendental functions, it may have practical value in resource-limited deep learning applications." Do you have any question that is not answered by the abstract of the squareplus paper? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: on reason we might generically be interested in smooth activation functions is that Gradient Descent has better theoretical properties than Subgradient Descent. (Whether or not these lead to practical differences is another question).

Comment: @Sycorax-OnStrike the comparison in that abstract is between squareplus and softplus, not squareplus and ReLU.

Comment: @JohnMadden In other words, a person could infer that the function proposed in that paper, and the problem that it solves, is not about the choice of squareplus versus relu, but squareplus versus softplus. -- So squareplus is not designed to replace relu, despite what the question asks.

Comment: @Sycorax-OnStrike the softplus itself is commonly viewed as a replacement for the ReLU (see e.g. this torch documentation https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Softplus.html). Hence by transitivity, it is in fact the case that the squareplus is functionally replacing ReLU. I think this question makes perfect sense.

Comment: @JohnMadden The only problem with replacing relu with softplus is that it performs worse. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/286358/22311

Comment: @Sycorax-OnStrike Sounds like you're conceding that it is interesting to consider when one might be preferable over the other?

Comment: Yep, you're right, it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Sycorax-OnStrike unless I'm missing something, that question is asking for benefits of the ReLU function over its smooth approximations, whereas this one is asking for the opposite.